# Getting error - ReferenceError: value is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, error-handling

I have following code:

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
  var contact = new Array();
  contact.push('<input type="text" class="id" data-val="'+v.id +'"value="' +v.id + '" />');
  contact.push('<select class="" data-val=' + v.course + ' onChange="Contact.update_here('+v.id +')"><option>....</option></select>');
 $('#table > tbody:first').append('<tr><td>' + contact.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>');
 });
```

Function:

```
update_here: function(check) {
alert(check);
    },
```

I am getting the error - `"ReferenceError: 101 is not defined"` (101 -> v.id)

Comment: the `data` you are iterating `$.each(data, function(k, v) {` don't have the `id`

Comment: can you check the generated html to see what if the value of the attribute `onchange`

Comment: <select .... onchange = update_here(101) .../>  - it seems 101 has to give in " "  - i tried to give but it gives "'missing ) after argument list"

Comment: @Bhushan : id? it is getting as v.id when iterating

Comment: `onChange="Contact.update_here(\''+v.id +'\')">` - but I don't think it will fix the issue

Comment: @Arun, seems that was the issue - I was giving ' as directly - \' worked. Thanks

Comment: where are you running the code... if it is in a browser that problem should not have occurred

Comment: @Futuregeek that should be have happened... can you share the generated html...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zbnj11pu/1 - it is working just fine

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `v.id` directly into function where browser take `101` as variable and not value, put this inside quotes as suggested by Arun using `\'`. See below code

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
  var contact = new Array();
  contact.push('<input type="text" class="id" data-val="'+v.id +'"value="' +v.id + '" />');
  contact.push('<select class="" data-val=' + v.course + ' onChange="Contact.update_here(\''+v.id +'\')"><option>....</option></select>');
 $('#table > tbody:first').append('<tr><td>' + contact.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>');
 });
```

Comment: that should not have caused any problem as `101` is an numerical literal... you will always call `fun(101)` not as `fun('101')`... I posted it as a comment because of that

Comment: As it is a valid literal browser should not take it as  a variable... but if you are passing a string like `abc` then I agree you need to wrap it in `''` to make it as a literal

Comment: but that works for OP. it may happend that 101 is coming as string and hence not working without quotes and looking it as variable.